# how to measure execution time of functions (automatically) in Python

Tags: python, oop

I need to have a *base class* which I will use to inherit other classes which I would like to measure execution time of its functions.

So **intead of** having something like this:

```
class Worker():
    def doSomething(self):
        start = time.time()
        ... do something
        elapsed = (time.time() - start)
        print "doSomething() took ", elapsed, " time to finish"

#outputs: doSomething() took XX time to finish
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
class Worker(BaseClass):
    def doSomething(self):
        ... do something

#outputs the same: doSomething() took XX time to finish
```

So the BaseClass needs to dealing with measuring time

Comment: I'd suggest a class decorator instead of implementing the timing in BaseClass.

Comment: Why not just use a profiler like cProfiler whenever you want to know the timings?

Comment: @Justin cProfiler is good but what I needed was to know about timings each time to report them.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One way to do this would be with a decorator [(PEP for decorators)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) [(first of a series of tutorial articles on decorators)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808). Here's an example that does what you want.

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timed(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
    start = time()
    result = f(*args, **kwds)
    elapsed = time() - start
    print "%s took %d time to finish" % (f.__name__, elapsed)
    return result
  return wrapper
```

This is an example of its use

```
@timed
def somefunction(countto):
  for i in xrange(countto):
    pass
  return "Done"
```

To show how it works I called the function from the python prompt:

```
>>> timedec.somefunction(10000000)
somefunction took 0 time to finish
'Done'
>>> timedec.somefunction(100000000)
somefunction took 2 time to finish
'Done'
>>> timedec.somefunction(1000000000)
somefunction took 22 time to finish
'Done'
```

Comment: Great example of clean code to show how decorators are one of the best joys in Python

Comment: @ronnieaka I'ts just the module name. I wrote the definitions of `timed` and `somefunction` in timedec.py and imported it from the interpreter to test them.

Comment: Good stuff. Thank you.

One thing to share with other people. It makes more sense to measure the execution time in milliseconds. e.g. Geoff's answer worked for me, but I only saw the following. 

```abc_function took 0 time to finish```.

This change will convert the time to milliseconds
```print "%s took %d milliSeconds to finish" % (f.__name__, elapsed*1000)```

Answer (score 10):

Have you checked the **["profile" module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/profile.htm)**?

I.e. are you sure you need to implement your own custom framework instead of using the default profiling mechanism for the language?

You could also google for "python hotshot" for a similar solution.

Answer (score 6):

There is also [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html), which is part of the standard library, and is really easy to use.  Remember: don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Indeed very simple and easy to use!

Comment: timeit seems promising! I will combine it with Geoff's solution.