# How to count time elapsed in Python multiple functions

Tags: python, timing

I am trying to count how long a very long process is taking:

```
import datetime

def main(argv):
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    for f in somearray:
        doSomething(f)
    endtime = datetime.datetime.now()
    deltatime = endtime-starttime
    print "Operation took " + str(deltatime.seconds) + " seconds"

def doSomething(f):
    # this takes a looong time (~10 minutes)
```

In the code above I only end up getting the time elapsed for the last time `doSomething` was run. I used to have `doSomething` as part of the `main` function and the timing was fine, but it made sense to move it to its own function.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245161/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-functions-automatically-in-python) but it seems to serve a different need.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: So you actually want to know how long it took to execute doSomethin once? Why don't you put it inside the method?

Comment: I want to know how long all of it took to execute (`f` occurrences of `doSomething`)

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? `datetime` doesn't have a `.seconds` attribute but it does have a `.second` attribute.  maybe try `str(deltatime.second)` in your code.

Comment: His `deltatime` is a `datetime.timedelta` instance, so it does have a `seconds` attribute.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'second'` Seconds works just fine. I get no error. The problem is that maybe `starttime` is getting overridden or reset somehow?