# How to use timeit where each test requires random setup

Tags: python, profiling, timeit

I have a function `f(x)` that takes as input a list `x` of 100 random floats between 0 and 1. Different lists will result in different running times of `f`.

I want to find out how long `f` takes to run on average, over a large number of different random lists. What's the best way to do this? Should I use `timeit` and if so is there a way I can do this without including the time it takes to generate each random list in each trial?

This is how I would do it without `timeit` (pseudocode):

```
for i = 1 to 10000:
    x = random list
    start = current time
    f(x)
    end = current time
    results.append(end - start)
return mean(results)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245161/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-functions-automatically-in-python

Comment: @lnwvr lol, I never saw that. If I did, I'd just copy it, no need to make my own decorator! :P

Answer (score 3):

You can make a timer decorator:

Here is some example code:

```
from time import time


class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        """
        Decorator that times a function
        @param func: Function being decorated
        @type func: callable
        """
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time()
        return end - start


@Timer
def cheese():
    for var in xrange(9999999):
        continue

for var in xrange(100):
    print cheese()
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/BFe0X8), with fewer loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit, random

def summer(myList):
    result = 0
    for num in myList:
        result += num
    return result

for i in range(10):
    x = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(100000)]
    print timeit.timeit("summer(x)", setup="from __main__ import x, summer", number = 100)
```

You can import the variable using `from __main__ import x`

Comment: Doesn't calling `timeit` a number of times in a loop defeat the purpose of using it though?

Comment: @Andrew You wanted to test the function with random inputs every time, right? Thats why its in a loop, with random input everytime.

Comment: @Andrew Its the same, but with `timeit` way of doing it.

Comment: `timeit` is not as flexible as I'd like. None the less, it is a way that you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick. It will execute the `setup` once per repeat and then execute `stmt` `number=1` time. However I don't think this is that much better than the simple loop you posted.

```
import timeit

stmt = '[x*x*x for x in xrange(n)]'  # just an example 
setup = 'import random; n = random.randint(10, 100)'
r = 10000
times = timeit.repeat(stmt, setup, repeat=r, number=1)

print min(times), max(times), sum(times)/r
```

There is also a "cell mode" that you can use with [timeit in the IPython shell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html#IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.timeit), but it only returns the fasted time and there is no easy way to change that (?).

```
import random

%%timeit -r 10000 -n 1 n = random.randint(10,100)
var = [x*x*x for x in xrange(n)]
```