# How to Find the total elapsed time for any function or any routine in python

Tags: python, function, time, elapsed

currently i'm using the below code to find elapsed time for any routine/functions that i manually use start time and end time all that

But, i want a fuction should automatically return the entire function took how long as if like when we run query and it use to say how many seconds and milli seconds like that i want to run any function and each function should return me with that elapsed time.

and here is my code and absolutely i'm not happy with this and i want a high end professional line of code's pls help. Thanks.

```
def ElaspedTime(stime,etime):
    from datetime import timedelta
    timediff = timedelta(seconds=etime - stime)
    return timediff

def STime():
    return time.monotonic()

def ETime():
    return time.monotonic()

#start_time = time.monotonic()

##call functions here

#end_time = time.monotonic()

#print( ElaspedTime(start_time,end_time))
```

Comment: Define professional? Also how else are you suppose to calculate a function's run time without having a start point, an end point, and a calculation called..?

Comment: As a side note, next time, highlight your code, and hit `ctrl`+`k`.

Comment: long since answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure time elapsed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python)

Comment: Thanks buddy...Prof --> Not too childish kind. and i have found some function for time and just say @timefunction before the call of any function it throw that elapsed time...i look for something like that

Comment: @PhilCooper absolutely not of this type i want one like the below runwithtime or @timefunction(functionname) like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to measure execution time of functions (automatically) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245161/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-functions-automatically-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper function like this:

```
def runWithTime(f,*args):
    from datetime import timedelta
    import time
    stime = time.time()
    r = f(*args)
    etime = time.time()
    timediff = timedelta(etime - stime)
    print timediff
    return r

def a(x,y):
    return x+y

r = runWithTime(a,1,2)
print r
```

Comment: Good and great idea bro...Thanks for the code but still i look for the proper one and this one is giving like this for 4:16:54.834595 a four second job...i saw some method of using prior to the function as @timefunction

Answer (score 0):

write a decorator as follow (replace log.debug with print ...):

```
from functools import wraps
def with_stopwatch(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kw):
        tstart = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        tend = time()
        log.debug('>>> func:%r took: %2.4f sec' % (f.__name__, tend - tstart))
        return result
    return wrapped

@with_stopwatch
def function()
    ...
```